# Spring Access Parameter Annotation Value in Rest Controller Advice

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, exceptionhandler, controller-advice

Is it possible to access parameter annotation value in restcontroller advice.In my case MyApiRequest is not valid for that reason I got 400 error.In restcontrolleradvice I catch this error and Also want some logging with myparameter value.But I cant access myparameter value in handleMethodArgumentNotValid exception

```
@PostMapping(path = "myapi")
public ResponseEntity<MyApiResponse> helloWorld(@RequestBody @Valid MyApiRequest request,@Myannotation final String myparameter)


public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

  @Override
  protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(
      MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
      HttpHeaders headers,
      HttpStatusCode status,
      WebRequest request) {
```

Comment: what do you mean by `@Myannotation` here? if it is a `@RequestParam` or what ever param that related to the request, you can get that value by using   `WebRequest ` object.